# books/paper recommendation on computational thermal-turbulence by using FEM

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics

I have just learned basic FEM for 2D N-S euqation, now my teacher let me to do the following problem, the document of this problem is in [large fluid problem](https://doc.freefem.org/tutorials/aLargeFluidProblem.html), the system of equations is listed in that page, I don't even know what is the boundary condition, could you please recommend some textbooks or papers for solving the following system of equations by using FEM?thank you very much.$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t \theta+u \nabla \theta-\nabla \cdot\left(\kappa_T^m \nabla \theta\right) & =0 \\
\partial_t u+u \nabla u-\nabla \cdot\left(\mu_T \nabla u\right)+\nabla p+e\left(\theta-\theta_0\right) \vec{e}_2 & =0 \\
\nabla \cdot u & =0 \\
\mu_T & =c_\mu \frac{k^2}{\epsilon} \\
\kappa_T & =\kappa \mu_T \\
\partial_t k+u \nabla k+\epsilon-\nabla \cdot\left(\mu_T \nabla k\right) & =\frac{\mu_T}{2}\left|\nabla u+\nabla u^T\right|^2 \\
\partial_t \epsilon+u \nabla \epsilon+c_2 \frac{\epsilon^2}{k}-\frac{c_\epsilon}{c_\mu} \nabla \cdot\left(\mu_T \nabla \epsilon\right) & =\frac{c_1}{2} k\left|\nabla u+\nabla u^T\right|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
I want to know the boundary conditions, choose of element, method of transform the nonlinear term to linear term,could you please recommend some books or papers, thank you

Comment: This is called the $k$-$\varepsilon$ set of equations for modeling turbulence. Have you looked at books that describe turbulence modeling?

Comment: I have found one detailed book